# Share GroupStyle between ListViews

Tags: wpf, listview, grouping, wpf-style

Is there a way to share code for GroupStyle/Columns between ListViews.

I have the settings working for one ListView, but since I want the same styling for two more, I don't want to copy the code, making the file cluttered. Plus one change in one of the ListViews, might be forgotten to be copied to the other.

I know that I can use styles in Window.Resources, and I made it work for columns, but the grouping I can't get to work.

I have the items loaded from ObservableCollection > ListCollectionView > ItemsSource with binding in PowerShell, working like a charm.

Xaml that works for one ListView:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="lvAllFiles">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="1000"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Created}" Header="Created" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastWriteTime}" Header="LastWriteTime" Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding TT}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="14"/>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </Expander>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `GroupStyle` as resource with an `x:Key`, for example in `<Window.Resources>`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <GroupStyle x:Key="gs">
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="14"/>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </Expander>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</Window.Resources>
```

You can then reference it like this:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="lvAllFiles">
    ...
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="gs" />
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```